# How to place javascript in nested Master Pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a situation where on a page that has a nested master page needs to have a peice of java script.  And i'm really unsure of where/how to add the javascript.

My layout is as follows:
Master.masterpage(top master page);
Client.MasterPage(which inheirts Master.masterpage)
assort.aspx(which inheirts client.masterpage);

In assort.aspx I need to have the following javascript available so on a onclick it will pop open a new window.

```
function ShowPopUpDialog(url) {
    window.open(url, 'MyPopUpWindow', 'height = 300px, width = 300px', true);
}
```

Where/how do I place the javascript.  I only want this active on assort.aspx, so I should only place it on Client.Masterpage correct?  If not where do I place it on assort.aspx?  There is no head section.

Here is my Client.MasterPage:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link href="css/valet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContactPlaceHolder_Header" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_Navigation" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_Content" runat="Server">
    <div class="InfoContainer">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentInfo" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="CRadGrid">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="RadGridPlaceHolder" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="MultiPage">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MultiPageContainer" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

My assort.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentInfo" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="RadGridPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MultiPageContainer" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this page is an exception, I would suggest the KISS principle, ie place a script tag close to where it will be used. If you'll need more scripts on more pages, then a content place holder maybe fits better.

Client master page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link href="css/valet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ClientHead" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

Assort.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="ClientHead" Runat="Server">        
   <script>
       function ShowPopUpDialog(url) {
          window.open(url, 'MyPopUpWindow', 'height = 300px, width = 300px', true);
       }
   </script>
</asp:Content>
```